# C# Cannot start Tensorflow: dll missing

Tags: c#, tensorflow

I'm trying to run my first tensorflow sample in C#, but I just don't succeed in getting it started. I always get the error that it can't load the dll tensorflow.
The error appears on the first call to create a placeholder.

Steps taken so far unsuccessfully:

- install c++ redistr 2019
- use framework 4.7.2
- run in x64
- following packages are installed (amongst others):

  - TensorFlow.NET
  - SciSharp TensorFlow Redist
  - Microsoft ML TensorFlow
  - Microsoft ML TensorFlow.redist
  - Microsoft ML

Any more ideas what could cause this?
Thanks!

Comment: please post your boilerplate project code to git or gist, so members can load the project and look at the problem without spending so much time on setting up the project while resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after some more googling, it appears that Tensorflow needs the AVX instruction set. My CPU is an i7 860 lynnfeld generation. And this instruction set is not yet included :(